# What happens behind the git command "git merge pr --squash"

Tags: git

Say you have a master branch to which you want to merge your feature branch onto with a merge --squash that will happen if you setup a pull request as squash merge.

To my understanding in a 'high level' explanation the feature branch would get copied by checking out a temp branch on the head of the feature branch. Now onto this temp feature branch all the commits would be rebased interactively so all the commits that diverged from the ancestor commit would be squashed onto this temp feature branch.

Then that temp feature branch gets rebased onto master so after that the master can just fast forward merge to that new sqaushed commit and the temp feature branch gets deleted.

Leaving the master branch with that new commit that includes all changes on the feature branch but has no 'merge connection/relationship' to the last commit on that feature branch.

Normally in the pull request the source branch, in this case the feature branch, will also be deleted. If you don't do that you would still have a unmerged feature branch with the same state as before the pull request.

Is my 'high level' understanding correct or is the process of a squash merge different behind the curtains?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tested it to make sure your understanding is correct?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, How can I test it? While doing a merge --squash you don't get a lot of usefull information.

Comment: You can try it out here https://git-school.github.io/visualizing-git/

Comment: @evolutionxbox, Wow thanks! I am gonna try out some scenarios with this interface! :)

Comment: It doesn’t do everything, but it definitely help visualise what’s going on behind the scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing together several concepts that *must* be kept separate.  In particular, a *pull request* is a GitHub (or other web service provider) feature.  This is not something *Git* does.<sup>1</sup>  Meanwhile `git merge` is a Git command-line command that operates within *your own* repository located on your own computer (laptop or whatever).  When working with GitHub pull requests, you—or whoever agrees to the request, at least—may manipulate some browser button(s) to do a "merge", a "rebase and merge", or a "squash and merge", and those make changes in a repository hosted on GitHub.  These are related, but different in several important ways, the biggest one being *who actually has the repository*.  Once you have more than one Git repository, it's crucial to keep in mind which one has which commits pointed-to by which branch names, because *your* branch names are *yours*, and theirs are theirs: they need not have anything to do with each other, even if they're both called `master` or `topic` or `feature/short` or whatever.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git has a `git request-pull` command, which generates (but does not send) email messages.  This is clearly not the same as a GitHub-style pull request.

---

#### The word *merge*, in Git, is both a noun and a verb

The [gitglossary](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary) defines **merge** this way:

> As a verb: To bring the contents of another [branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#def_branch) (possibly from an external [repository](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#def_repository)) into the current branch. In the case where the merged-in branch is from a different repository, this is done by first [fetching](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#def_fetch) the remote branch and then merging the result into the current branch. This combination of fetch and merge operations is called a [pull](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#def_pull). Merging is performed by an automatic process that identifies changes made since the branches diverged, and then applies all those changes together. In cases where changes conflict, manual intervention may be required to complete the merge.
>
> As a noun: unless it is a [fast-forward](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#def_fast_forward), a successful merge results in the creation of a new [commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#def_commit) representing the result of the merge, and having as [parents](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#def_parent) the tips of the merged [branches](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#def_branch). This commit is referred to as a "merge commit", or sometimes just a "merge".

There is a lot packed into these two paragraphs, and I'm not a fan of wedging the definition of "pull" *into* that of the verb merge—especially since `git pull` can be told to run `git rebase` instead of `git merge` as its second Git command—but the verb/noun distinction is here.  When you do the action—the *verb as a merge* part—you often get the noun-or-adjective, i.e., the *merge commit*, as the result.

#### With this in mind, let's look at the anatomy of actual merges

Ignoring `git pull` (which just runs `git merge` *for* you, unless you tell it otherwise), the way you invoke the main merge-as-a-verb operation is to run:

```
git merge <thing-to-specify-a-commit>
```

from the command line.  The commit specifier argument can be a branch name, a tag name, a raw commit hash ID, or anything that allows Git to find one particular commit.

Commits, in Git, exist in the form of a *graph*, specifically a Directed Acyclic Graph or DAG.  Each commit is identified by its own unique hash ID—the hash ID is essentially the true name of the commit, and this one particular name is used in *every* Git repository everywhere to mean *that one particular commit*, if that commit is in that Git repository at all.  Meanwhile, each commit contains, as part of its metadata, the actual hash ID(s) of its parent(s).

Mathematically, the definition of a graph is *G = (V, E)* where *V* is a set of vertices (or nodes) and *E* is a set of edges connecting those nodes.  In Git, the nodes are commits—identified by their hash IDs—and the edges are one-way links or *arcs*, pointing from the child commit to its parent(s).  These one-way links let Git move about, starting at the child-most commits.  This gives us a bunch of ways to *draw* the graph.  For StackOverflow postings, the way I like is to write them down like this, with newer commits towards the right:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Here each letter stands in for an actual hash ID, and the arrows coming from a letter are the edges / arcs: if `H` is a commit, it holds the hash ID of its parent `G`, so `H` *points to* `G`.  `G` holds the hash ID of `F`, so `G` points to `F`, and so on.  These arrows all go backwards—a typical DAG has the arrow going *from* the parents, *to* the children, but Git prefers to work backwards (for various good reasons).<sup>2</sup>  For our own convenience, though, we can just start drawing them without any arrow-direction at all, and just remember that Git does things backwards:

```
...--F--G--H
```

In the forward direction—the one Git doesn't actually do—commit `F` has one child `G`, and `G` has one child `H`.  From here, let's have `H` acquire *two* children, each of which has one of its own children:

```
             I--J
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             K--L
```

For Git to *find* these commits, it needs some branch names.  The branch *names* hold the actual hash ID of the *last* commit in the branch—which implies that every time we add a *new* commit to the branch, the value associated with the name changes—but let's just draw this in now:

```
             I--J   <-- br1
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             K--L   <-- br2
```

In order to make a merge—to run the verb kind of merge—we'll pick one branch to check out, such as `br1`, and then run `git merge` on the other one:

```
git checkout br1
git merge br2
```

This will kick off the merge-as-a-verb process.  If all goes well, it will make a *merge commit*, which is simply a commit with at least two parents:<sup>3</sup>

```
             I--J
            /    \
...--F--G--H      M   <-- br1 (HEAD)
            \    /
             K--L   <-- br2
```

This new merge commit `M` gets added as the *last* commit on the current branch `br1`, so that the *name* `br1` now points to new merge commit `M`.

Git actually computes the *contents*—the merged files—for merge commit `M` using *three* inputs: the two tip commits—here, `J` and `L`—and the *merge base* commit, which is defined as the *best common ancestor* of the other two commits.  In this particular case, the best common ancestor is easy to see: it's commit `H`.<sup>4</sup>  You can think of the way Git handles this as:

- run `git diff --find-renames hash-of-H hash-of-J` to see what *we* changed;
- run `git diff --find-renames hash-of-H hash-of-L` to see what *they* changed;
- combine these two diff outputs, applying the combined changes to the files from commit `H`.

Ignoring all the mechanics of conflict resolution, and the various special non-merge cases that `git merge` can do, this is really the key to any merge.  **Git finds the common starting-point commit, makes two sets of diffs, combines them, and applies the combined diffs to the common starting point snapshot.**  This forms the snapshot for the merge result.

---

<sup>2</sup>In particular, *everything* inside the main Git object database—commits and files, plus various glue objects—is frozen for all time.  Git needs this to make its hash IDs work.  A commit knows its *parent or parents* at the time it gets created: their hash IDs already exist.  The commit *does not* know its children yet.  The commit has just been born!  Its memory is now frozen.  Eventually, *later*, it acquires its first child.  The parent cannot learn its child's hash ID, because the commit is already frozen for all time.  The same holds if and when the parent gets a second child, third child, and so on.  The children know their parents, but the parents don't know their children.

<sup>3</sup>Git calls a merge commit with three or more parents an *octopus merge*.  There's nothing you can do with an octopus merge that you cannot do with a series of ordinary merges—in fact, the opposite is true: you can do things with ordinary merges that Git will refuse to do as a single octopus merge.  The fact that an octopus merge is *weaker* than regular merges is somewhat useful, when you're examining a new-to-you repository, in that you can be reasonably assured that this merge doesn't introduce secret changes, nor have any conflict resolutions.  But other version control systems that only allow pair-of-commit merges are just as *powerful* as Git.

<sup>4</sup>Technically, the merge base is the Lowest Common Ancestor of the two commits, using a generalized form of the LCA algorithm.  LCAs are well defined on trees—the graph fragment I show above is actually a tree rather than a DAG—but in DAGs there may be more than one LCA.  In this particular answer I'm not going to go into how Git handles the multiple-LCA case.

---

#### The squash merge is now trivial

Once you understand all of the above, `git merge --squash` becomes ridiculously simple.  Git does *everything it would do for a real merge*, and then, at the end, it makes a commit that has *one* parent instead of *two*.<sup>5</sup>

That is, we start out with:

```
             I--J   <-- br1
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             K--L   <-- br2
```

and run `git checkout br1; git merge --squash br2`.  Git finds merge base `H`, performs two diffs, combines the diffs, and applies those to the contents of `H`.  Then Git makes—well, makes *you* make; see footnote 5—the new merge commit, but instead of `M` with parents `J` and `L`, Git makes a commit we might want to call `S` (for squash) with *one* parent, `J`:

```
             I--J--S   <-- br1
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             K--L   <-- br2
```

Had Git made merge `M`—and we can in fact still make `M`, the *hashes* wouldn't match, but the *snapshots* of `M` and `S` would.  You can confirm this by making `M`:

```
git checkout -b experiment <hash-of-J>
git merge br2
```

which results in:

```
             I--J--S   <-- br1
            /    \
...--F--G--H      M   <-- experiment (HEAD)
            \    /
             K--L   <-- br2
```

The *contents* of `M` and `S` will match:

```
git diff br1 experiment
```

will show nothing at all.

---

<sup>5</sup>When you run `git merge --squash`, Git makes you run `git commit` yourself.  The `--squash` flag turns on the `--no-commit` flag.  This is a leftover from an ancient version of Git where `--squash` simply made `git merge` exit *before* running `git commit`—a true merge actually invokes `git commit` at the end, unless you use `--no-commit` or the merge has conflicts.

Comment: I know it's late but hhanks for the thorough explanation!